# Setting up Emacs for Haskell development fights with Evil-mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode, haskell-mode

I've recently switched from vim to emacs using evil mode and while coding with clojure has been a pleasure, I've found out that the haskell environment doesn't cope well with evil-mode... in particular, the "o", "O" and "RET" (while in insert mode) commands break the current indentation when they open a new line. Example:

```
say :: String |
```

press "o"..

```
say :: String
       |
```

That's quite annoying but I've found this solution in another answer:

```
    (defun evil-open-below (count)
    "Insert a new line below point and switch to Insert state.
    The insertion will be repeated COUNT times."
    (interactive "p")
    (evil-insert-newline-below)
    (setq evil-insert-count count
            evil-insert-lines t
            evil-insert-vcount nil)
    (evil-insert-state 1)
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'evil-maybe-remove-spaces)
    )
```

That is, overriding every key, but for some reason the "O" equivalent isn't working:

```
    (defun evil-open-above (count)
    "Insert a new line above point and switch to Insert state.
    The insertion will be repeated COUNT times."
    (interactive "p")
    (evil-insert-newline-above)
    (setq evil-insert-count count
            evil-insert-lines t
            evil-insert-vcount nil)
    (evil-insert-state 1)
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'evil-maybe-remove-spaces)
    )
```

Also, how would have it do the same for the RET key?

Comment: Is the pipe character (`|`) where the cursor is or a literal pipe character in the file that gets moved when you press `o`?

Comment: Hi, with | I mean the cursor. Sorry for not specifying it